# Why do subsequent copy operations for the same file and destination get slower (windows)

Tags: windows, windows-10, filesystems, file-transfer

I am writing a little test suite to compare the speed of different file copy techniques. I have a number of different methods that I want to test and I run each test 5 times with a 500ms break between each test.

The results look like this ever time:

```
Running Test: Windows Native Copy 1/5 (788)... ✓
Running Test: Windows Native Copy 2/5 (1034)... ✓
Running Test: Windows Native Copy 3/5 (2536)... ✓
Running Test: Windows Native Copy 4/5 (2559)... ✓
Running Test: Windows Native Copy 5/5 (3024)... ✓
Windows Native Copy Average: 1988 Best: 788
```

The source and destination folders are on the same disk. Obviously the destination filename is different for each test.
This drive is a Raid 0 array of 3 ssds.

I assume that this is a caching issue of some sort but if that were the case I'd expect the numbers to get better!

Comment: Your test may be affected by the SSD internal write cache. Modern consumer SSDs are pretty slow on writing and they "hide" this by reserving a small section of the SSD as fast write cache. If that write cache is full the write speed drops. In cheap SSDs with 3 or 4 bits per flash cell, writing speed can drop even below an HDD write rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple factors which contribute to SSDs becoming temporally slower over time:

- SSDs consist of a small amount of very fast non-volatile [(SLC)](https://www.howtogeek.com/444787/multi-layer-ssds-what-are-slc-mlc-tlc-qlc-and-mlc/) cells and mostly slower regular cells

  - SLC cells are responsible for the fast write speeds seen in the first couple of GB (e.g. 500 MB/s). When activity allows, the drive will unload its SLC cache to regular cells
  - Size of the SLC part varies between drives sizes/manufacturers and is often a percentage of overall drive size
  - Once the SLC part is full, your drive will revert back to its "standard" Cells which might be MLC (2-bit) TLC (3-bit), or even QLC (4-bit, very slow). Usually those non SLC cells are not able to sustain your interfaces throughput of e.g. 500 MB/s for SATA 6 Gbit/s.
  - -> Your "real" speed might only be 150-300 Mbit/s. If you have a more premium SSD, especially a 2-Bit/MLC SSD, its "slower" cells might be sufficiently fast sustain faster speeds.
- SSDs must clear cells before they can be written again [(Garbage Collection)](https://datarecovery.com/rd/garbage-collection-ssd-simple-explanation/)

  - Once the drive becomes somewhat fuller, it must start reclaiming written and partially written cells by clearing them to an empty state
  - Cells containing obsolete data will be cleared outright, while partially written cells require their data to be moved to other cells, further slowing the drive down. This is why some drives advertise their Garbage Collection/Trim prowess, which preemptively attempt to prepare the drive for new data

A non obvious fact of SSDs, is that larger SSDs models of the same series (e.g. Samsung 860 Pro), are created with more chips. These chips can be accessed in parallel and result in increased speed over their smaller siblings. So bigger SSDs are usually faster. You can compare performance of different sizes [here](https://www.anandtech.com/show/15887/the-samsung-870-qvo-1tb-4tb-ssd-review-qlc-refreshed/2),